# Significantly different "weights" and "bias" of two NN trained using same data

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I recently got introduced to the magical world of neural networks. I started following the [Neural Networks and Deep Learning](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/index.html) which implement a NN to recognize handwritten digits. It implements a 3 layer network( 1 input, 1 hidden, and 1 output) and trained using MNIST data set.

I just found that the weights matrix of two NN having a similar layer [784,30,10] architecture and trained using the same data set is very different. The same is true for the bias matrix.

General intuition says that since we are using multiple epochs and randomizing the data at each epoch, the weight matrix of both NN should converge to similar values. But it turns out to be very different. Would could be the reason for the same?

Here is the first few weights of NN1:

```
[array([[-1.2129184 , -0.08418661, -1.58413842, ...,  0.14350188,
          1.49436597, -1.71864906],
        [ 0.25485346, -0.1795214 ,  0.14175609, ...,  0.4222159 ,
          1.28005992, -1.17403326],
        [ 1.09796094,  0.66119858,  1.12603969, ...,  0.23220572,
         -1.66863656,  0.02761243],.....
```

Here is the first few weights of NN2, having same number of layers and trained using same training data, epochs and eta.

```
[array([[-0.87264811,  0.34475347, -0.04876076, ..., -0.074056  ,
          0.10218085, -0.50177084],
        [-1.96657944, -0.35619652,  1.10898861, ..., -0.53325862,
         -1.52680967,  0.26800431],
        [-1.24731848,  0.13278103, -1.70306514, ...,  0.07964225,
         -0.88724451, -0.40311485],
        ...,
```

Comment: There is a lot of randomness involved here. Two important types: 1) how weights are initialized before training and 2) how the training examples are shuffled. Certain kinds of randomness can be fixed by setting random seeds, depending on the framework / libraries you are using, but some operations might still be non-deterministic. Bottom line: never assume that training twice leads to the same results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> General intuition says that since we are using multiple epochs and
>   randomizing the data at each epoch, the weight matrix of both NN
>   should converge to similar values

Unfortunately this is not true. This is because the loss landscape of neural networks is very complex, with lots of local minima that generalize quite well. Because of the random nature of the initialization and the training procedure, you are essentially guaranteed to converge to a different set of parameters with good performance.

Also note that randomness is not sufficient to have different results. For example, linear regression would always converge to the same parameters regardless of the initial values and order of the examples. Convergence to the same parameters is guaranteed only for *convex* loss functions.

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful explanation. It's a little out of context to ask here, but I couldn't comment on the original question page, so reaching for help here.
I tried to implement the query in the following link using two ways, 1) A new NN model to transform output back to input. 2) As, suggested, Using backpropagation on a pre-trained NN with given output and **unknown Input**. The first one seems to work and 2nd didn't. Could you add your insights about it here or on the question page, link below
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131088/find-neural-network-inputs-given-outputs

Comment: @NipunPruthi that second method should work. Why don't you ask a new question on this website and provide more details?

Comment: okay :), actually they don't allow asking two questions in a short amount of time, for a new account

Comment: Unless I get thumbs up on the question :')

Answer (score 0):

The weights of the two NN definitely won't be the same, unless a major coincidence.

This is because the initial weights that you assign are random, and also like you have mentioned in your question 'the data at each epoch is randomly chosen'.

Comment: I am new at this, therefore, didn't get it!! I can be wrong in asking this, so, please be kind.
As the gradient descent is to move the weights in the direction to minimize the cost function and reach the function minima. Why the weights aren't converging to the same value. After all, we are traversing the data multiple times in both NN.

Comment: Could we say that multiple weights combinations exist? If yes, then, we might reach the function minima that's not the global minima of it and after applying gradient descent, we might stuck in it. How we can make sure to reach global minima of the cost function 
And doesn't "randomly chosen" data is used to converge the values of the weights.